# Python unhashable type: 'OrderedDict'

Tags: python, exception, dictionary

I am not at all unfamiliar with the concept of:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'OrderedDict'
```

But I can not understand how the following line of codes can produce such a stack-trace.

```
89:     @staticmethod
90:     def diff(var1, var2, path=[], level=0, curpath=[]):
...
101:        elif isinstance(var1, list) and isinstance(var2, list):
102:            l1s = set(var1)
103:            l2s = set(var2)
104:            retlist = []

  File "myFile.py", line 102, in diff
    l1s = set(var1)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'OrderedDict'
```

How can line `102`, in the above code throw such an exception?

Comment: `var1` is a list of `OrderedDict`s.

Comment: As an aside, you may want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @PavelAnossov, I am banging my head against my desk now :) thanks, don´t know how I missed that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some data structures (most notably `dict`s and `set`s) require objects they contain (keys in the case of dictionaries, items in the case of sets) to implement the `__hash__()` magic method, so that calling `hash(obj)` returns a value.

This is required to optimize the structure, and together with immutability to help guarantee uniqueness of contained objects.

In your case, `var1` contains some object that is not *hashable* (it does not implement `hash()`). This object is an `OrderedDict`, which is a mutable object and is not hashable by design.

As an example of an other object type which is mutable and not hashable by design, consider `list` and this example:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> set([L])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> hash(L)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

If you're using `set()` to ensure uniqueness then you must go some other way, though it's not clear from your question.

Answer (score 4):

dict(including OrderedDict) in python are mutable containers.

If a dict was hashed, its hash value would be changed as long as you changed the dict's contents.

Answer (score 1):

Sets in python are based on hashes. OrderedDicts are not hashable.