# Changing Series/List of OrderedDicts to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a dataframe of 533,668 active business registries from the County Assessor's office in an excel spreadsheet. I want to get the Addresses (currently all in one column) broken up into the AddressNumber, StreetName, StreetType, UnitNumber, City, State, etc., and I have a library (pyusaddress), which can parse through the column. I used

```
`def clean_address(row):
    try:
        prep_address = usaddress.tag(row)
        address = prep_address[0]
    except usaddress.RepeatedLabelError as e :
        print(e.parsed_string)
        print(e.original_string)
        address = 'Duplicate Address'
    except TypeError:
        address = "Invalid Address"
    return address

address_list = active_businesses['STREET ADDRESS'].apply(clean_address)`
```

The problem with this is that I get a list of OrderedDicts, which I then need to parse through to get a dataframe. I tried a for loop, but it was incredibly slow, so I wanted to know if anyone had any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the apply method is basically a for loop under the hood. You may get a better performance throught the np.vectorize method which works pretty much the same and has given me a better performance in the past. Refer to this post [Performance of Pandas apply vs np.vectorize to create new column from existing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c)

Regarding OrderedDicts there is nothing much you can do than try to parse it in a efficient way, maybe this thread can help you in that sense [How to create a Pandas DataFrame from a list of OrderedDicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902158/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-list-of-ordereddicts)