# Create pandas dataframe from ordered dict fails

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following python method that I got it from the selected answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52902158/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-list-of-ordereddicts):

```
def _dataframe_from_ordered_dict(self, source_data):
        return pd.DataFrame([source_data[i][0] for i, j in enumerate(source_data)])
```

The problem is that I am getting this error: `[source_data[i][0] for i, j in enumerate(source_data)]) KeyError: 0`.

**EDIT**
This is a subset of the content of `source_data`, it raises the same error:

```
[OrderedDict([('\ufeffZipcode', '1606'), ('primary_city', 'Worcester'), ('state', 'MA'), ('AXLE_CA_Local_Zone', '2'), ('AXLE_DS_Zone', '2'), ('ASCR_DS_Zone', '2'), ('CDL_NJ_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_GA_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_TPAFL_Zone', ''), ('GLS_CA_Local_Zone', ''), ('GLS_Surcharge', ''), ('TFRC_DS_Zone', '2'), ('LSR_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), 
('LSR_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('LSR_TX_Local_Zone', '2'), ('LSR_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ORL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('LSR_GROOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ATL_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('SPR_TX_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UDS_DS_Zone', ''), ('Veho_Local_Zone', '3'), ('Veho_DS_Zone', '2'), ('HFDN_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('UPS_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('UPS_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('UPS_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_PHOAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_PHXAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_HAPA_DS_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_DENCO_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_MEMTN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_POOR_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_RICA_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_KCMO_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ORLFL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ATLGA_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHI_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_COLOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_HAMD_DS_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_STPMN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_CYPRTX_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_SD_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_AZ_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SALUT_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_WILCT_DS_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_VBRMI_DS_Zone', '4')]),
OrderedDict([('\ufeffZipcode', '1607'), ('primary_city', 'Worcester'), ('state', 'MA'), ('AXLE_CA_Local_Zone', '2'), ('AXLE_DS_Zone', '2'), ('ASCR_DS_Zone', '2'), ('CDL_NJ_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_GA_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_TPAFL_Zone', ''), ('GLS_CA_Local_Zone', ''), ('GLS_Surcharge', ''), ('TFRC_DS_Zone', '2'), ('LSR_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), 
('LSR_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('LSR_TX_Local_Zone', '3'), ('LSR_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ORL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('LSR_GROOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ATL_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('SPR_TX_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UDS_DS_Zone', ''), ('Veho_Local_Zone', '3'), ('Veho_DS_Zone', '2'), ('HFDN_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('UPS_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('UPS_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('UPS_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_PHOAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_PHXAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_HAPA_DS_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_DENCO_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_MEMTN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_POOR_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_RICA_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_KCMO_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ORLFL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ATLGA_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHI_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_COLOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_HAMD_DS_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_STPMN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_CYPRTX_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_SD_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_AZ_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SALUT_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_WILCT_DS_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_VBRMI_DS_Zone', '4')]),
OrderedDict([('\ufeffZipcode', '1608'), ('primary_city', 'Worcester'), ('state', 'MA'), ('AXLE_CA_Local_Zone', '2'), ('AXLE_DS_Zone', '2'), ('ASCR_DS_Zone', '2'), ('CDL_NJ_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_GA_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_TPAFL_Zone', ''), ('GLS_CA_Local_Zone', ''), ('GLS_Surcharge', ''), ('TFRC_DS_Zone', '2'), ('LSR_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), 
('LSR_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('LSR_TX_Local_Zone', '3'), ('LSR_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ORL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('LSR_GROOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ATL_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('SPR_TX_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UDS_DS_Zone', ''), ('Veho_Local_Zone', '3'), ('Veho_DS_Zone', '2'), ('HFDN_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('UPS_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('UPS_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('UPS_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_PHOAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_PHXAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_HAPA_DS_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_DENCO_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_MEMTN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_POOR_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_RICA_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_KCMO_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ORLFL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ATLGA_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHI_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_COLOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_HAMD_DS_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_STPMN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_CYPRTX_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_SD_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_AZ_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SALUT_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_WILCT_DS_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_VBRMI_DS_Zone', '4')]),
OrderedDict([('\ufeffZipcode', '1609'), ('primary_city', 'Worcester'), ('state', 'MA'), ('AXLE_CA_Local_Zone', '2'), ('AXLE_DS_Zone', '2'), ('ASCR_DS_Zone', '2'), ('CDL_NJ_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_GA_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_TPAFL_Zone', ''), ('GLS_CA_Local_Zone', ''), ('GLS_Surcharge', ''), ('TFRC_DS_Zone', '2'), ('LSR_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), 
('LSR_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('LSR_TX_Local_Zone', '3'), ('LSR_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ORL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('LSR_GROOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ATL_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('SPR_TX_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UDS_DS_Zone', ''), ('Veho_Local_Zone', '3'), ('Veho_DS_Zone', '2'), ('HFDN_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('UPS_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('UPS_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('UPS_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_PHOAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_PHXAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_HAPA_DS_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_DENCO_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_MEMTN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_POOR_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_RICA_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_KCMO_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ORLFL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ATLGA_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHI_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_COLOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_HAMD_DS_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_STPMN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_CYPRTX_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_SD_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_AZ_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SALUT_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_WILCT_DS_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_VBRMI_DS_Zone', '4')])]
```

I don't know what I am missing if I am following the answer as it is.

Comment: What is your `source_data`? Can you please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't guess how does `source_data` look like and what should be the expected output. Most likely your data doesn't have the same structure as in the example of that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

l = [OrderedDict([('\ufeffZipcode', '1606'), ('primary_city', 'Worcester'), ('state', 'MA'), ('AXLE_CA_Local_Zone', '2'), ('AXLE_DS_Zone', '2'), ('ASCR_DS_Zone', '2'), ('CDL_NJ_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_GA_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_TPAFL_Zone', ''), ('GLS_CA_Local_Zone', ''), ('GLS_Surcharge', ''), ('TFRC_DS_Zone', '2'), ('LSR_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'),
('LSR_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('LSR_TX_Local_Zone', '2'), ('LSR_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ORL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('LSR_GROOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ATL_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('SPR_TX_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UDS_DS_Zone', ''), ('Veho_Local_Zone', '3'), ('Veho_DS_Zone', '2'), ('HFDN_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('UPS_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('UPS_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('UPS_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_PHOAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_PHXAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_HAPA_DS_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_DENCO_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_MEMTN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_POOR_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_RICA_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_KCMO_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ORLFL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ATLGA_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHI_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_COLOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_HAMD_DS_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_STPMN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_CYPRTX_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_SD_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_AZ_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SALUT_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_WILCT_DS_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_VBRMI_DS_Zone', '4')]),
OrderedDict([('\ufeffZipcode', '1607'), ('primary_city', 'Worcester'), ('state', 'MA'), ('AXLE_CA_Local_Zone', '2'), ('AXLE_DS_Zone', '2'), ('ASCR_DS_Zone', '2'), ('CDL_NJ_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_GA_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_TPAFL_Zone', ''), ('GLS_CA_Local_Zone', ''), ('GLS_Surcharge', ''), ('TFRC_DS_Zone', '2'), ('LSR_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'),
('LSR_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('LSR_TX_Local_Zone', '3'), ('LSR_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ORL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('LSR_GROOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ATL_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('SPR_TX_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UDS_DS_Zone', ''), ('Veho_Local_Zone', '3'), ('Veho_DS_Zone', '2'), ('HFDN_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('UPS_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('UPS_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('UPS_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_PHOAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_PHXAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_HAPA_DS_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_DENCO_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_MEMTN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_POOR_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_RICA_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_KCMO_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ORLFL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ATLGA_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHI_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_COLOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_HAMD_DS_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_STPMN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_CYPRTX_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_SD_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_AZ_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SALUT_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_WILCT_DS_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_VBRMI_DS_Zone', '4')]),
OrderedDict([('\ufeffZipcode', '1608'), ('primary_city', 'Worcester'), ('state', 'MA'), ('AXLE_CA_Local_Zone', '2'), ('AXLE_DS_Zone', '2'), ('ASCR_DS_Zone', '2'), ('CDL_NJ_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_GA_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_TPAFL_Zone', ''), ('GLS_CA_Local_Zone', ''), ('GLS_Surcharge', ''), ('TFRC_DS_Zone', '2'), ('LSR_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'),
('LSR_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('LSR_TX_Local_Zone', '3'), ('LSR_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ORL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('LSR_GROOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ATL_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('SPR_TX_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UDS_DS_Zone', ''), ('Veho_Local_Zone', '3'), ('Veho_DS_Zone', '2'), ('HFDN_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('UPS_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('UPS_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('UPS_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_PHOAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_PHXAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_HAPA_DS_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_DENCO_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_MEMTN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_POOR_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_RICA_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_KCMO_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ORLFL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ATLGA_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHI_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_COLOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_HAMD_DS_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_STPMN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_CYPRTX_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_SD_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_AZ_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SALUT_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_WILCT_DS_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_VBRMI_DS_Zone', '4')]),
OrderedDict([('\ufeffZipcode', '1609'), ('primary_city', 'Worcester'), ('state', 'MA'), ('AXLE_CA_Local_Zone', '2'), ('AXLE_DS_Zone', '2'), ('ASCR_DS_Zone', '2'), ('CDL_NJ_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_GA_Local_Zone', ''), ('CRX_TPAFL_Zone', ''), ('GLS_CA_Local_Zone', ''), ('GLS_Surcharge', ''), ('TFRC_DS_Zone', '2'), ('LSR_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'),
('LSR_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('LSR_TX_Local_Zone', '3'), ('LSR_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ORL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('LSR_GROOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_ATL_DS_Zone', '5'), ('LSR_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('SPR_TX_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UDS_DS_Zone', ''), ('Veho_Local_Zone', '3'), ('Veho_DS_Zone', '2'), ('HFDN_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('UPS_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('UPS_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('UPS_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('UPS_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('UPS_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_NJ_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_NT_Local_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_PA_Local_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_MD_Local_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_DL_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_GA_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_TX_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_CA_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_FW_Local_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_NW_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SE_Local_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_PHOAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_PHXAZ_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_HAPA_DS_Zone', '3'), ('FedEx_DENCO_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_MEMTN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_POOR_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_RICA_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_KCMO_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ORLFL_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_ATLGA_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHI_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_CHANC_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_COLOH_DS_Zone', '5'), ('FedEx_HAMD_DS_Zone', '4'), ('FedEx_STPMN_DS_Zone', '6'), ('FedEx_CYPRTX_DS_Zone', '7'), ('FedEx_SD_DS_Zone', '2'), ('UPS_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_Surcharge', ''), ('FDX_AZ_Local_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_SALUT_DS_Zone', '8'), ('FedEx_WILCT_DS_Zone', '2'), ('FedEx_VBRMI_DS_Zone', '4')])]


def dataframe_from_ordered_dict(source_data):
    return pd.DataFrame([source_data[i] for i, j in enumerate(source_data)])

df = dataframe_from_ordered_dict(l)
```